# How to pass method to EventCallback in Blazor Code Behind?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When using Blazor (.Net Core v3+) Code Behind I can't pass a method name to a component with an event callback parameter. However when using `@code { }` in the razor component, I can pass the method name to the component's event callback.

Compiler Error when using code behind, see below:

Argument 2: Cannot convert from method group to EventCallback.

```
@page "/localized-strings"

@inherits LocalizedStringTypesBase

<SfGrid DataSource="@MyDataSource">
    <!-- Argument 2: Error Here for RowSelected="OnDataGridRowSelect"  -->
    <GridEvents RowSelected="OnDataGridRowSelect" TValue="LocalizedStringType"></GridEvents>
</SfGrid>

public class LocalizedStringTypesBase : ComponentBase
{
    public void OnDataGridRowSelect(RowSelectEventArgs<LocalizedStringType> args)
    {
        // not implemented yet
    }
}
```

This error goes away with the `@code {  }` block, see below.

```
@page "/localized-strings"

<SfGrid DataSource="@MyDataSource">
    <!-- No Error Here for RowSelected="OnDataGridRowSelect"  -->
    <GridEvents RowSelected="OnDataGridRowSelect" TValue="LocalizedStringType"></GridEvents>
</SfGrid>


@code {

    public void OnDataGridRowSelect(RowSelectEventArgs<LocalizedStringType> args)
    {
    // not implemented yet
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method is public so it shouldn't be an issue to access from the razor file. Have you tried deleting the GridEvents component on the top example, running a build, and then adding it in again? That has caught me out in the past, where blazor just couldnt see it. The other thing you can try is setting the function as anonymous. ```RowSelected="@(() => OnDataGridRowSelect(args))"```.

Comment: That certainly looks like a bug. Out of interest, try changing your code behind to be a partial class with the same name as the component and drop the `@inherits` line

Comment: Had a similar problem, `RowSelected="@(e => OnDataGridRowSelect(e))"` worked for me.